# Angular (click) call function and lose focus

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I am using bootstrap which has a button styling where if I click the button and I lose focus it works fine.  I need to be able to call a function and then lose focus on the button on the click.  Example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
    style ="background-color: black; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; position:relative;" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

How can I achieve the save being called back to the TS file which works of course but then make it like I click anything else in the page.   When I do change focus it does what I want and the button goes back to normal styling.  Is there a way to like blur or set focus to another element etc in just the (click) event or another event I can use to `this.blur()` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) and call the [`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur) function on it.

```html
<button #button 
  type="button" 
  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
  style ="background-color: black; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; position:relative;" 
  (click)="button.blur(); save()"
>
  Save
</button>
```

Here the `#button` denotes the template reference variable and we're calling the `blur()` method in the handler section before calling the `save()` handler.